How can I use downloaded Go modules in an offline environment
We are working in an air-gapped environment, and we need to be able to upload, download and use Go modules within our air-gapped environment.
How should we setup our Artifactory repo? Do we need to use our GitLab instance to host our Go modules, and if so how should we configure it to be able to use it?
Current situation
We have an Artifactory server deployed locally as well as a hosted GitLab instance. Our development machines have network access to both via HTTPS.
What we tried
We downloaded modules on a machine with internet access using go get <module_name> command, and then uploaded the modules to a Go repo on Artifactory. Then, on our machines we set GOPROXY to the Artifactory URL as stated in the "Set me up" section of the Artifactory Go repo. Upon running go get <module_name>, we get a 404 error.

Can you just vendor your dependencies?

I tried doing that, but I want to be able to use the dependencies in multiple projects, not just in this one. Maybe there's something I don't get about vendoring but my understanding is you can use the dependencies you vendor only in your local environment right? Also I want to be abe to use my custom modules elsewhere, by downloading them from a registry of some sort

go mod vendor
Also check this answer

I recommend using Athens
On the machine with internet connection set up Athens using docker.
https://docs.gomods.io/
The easiest option is to use the disk storage type
(which you can later move to the air gaped machine)
by default Athens is configured to pull new modules that are not in  its storage.
after setting up Athens
run go get like so:
export GOPROXY=http://localhost:3000 && go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin

the setup on the air gaped machine is almost identical
just make sure to set this env variable
ATHENS_NETWORK_MODE=offline
which tells Athens to only use modules in it storage
services:
  athens:
    volumes:
      - <local path>:/var/lib/athens
    environment:
      - ATHENS_DISK_STORAGE_ROOT=/var/lib/athens
      - ATHENS_STORAGE_TYPE=disk
      - ATHENS_NETWORK_MODE=offline
      - ATHENS_DOWNLOAD_MODE=none
    container_name: athens-proxy
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3000:3000
    image: gomods/athens:latest

In your development machines edit the go config file
and change GOPROXY to the the URL of your Athens instance.

Seems like this would solve my problem, thx! What do I have to do to set it up as proxy to download modules in my offline environment?

go mod vendor

It can help.

The go mod vendor command constructs a directory named vendor in the
main module’s root directory that contains copies of all packages
needed to support builds and tests of packages in the main module.

